# get js parent class name from child class itself not it's instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

how i can get parent class name from child class itself in JS.

for example:

```
class Parent {}

class Child extends Parent {}

console.log(Child.parentName); // log: 'Parent'
```

i waiting for your's answer...

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
class Parent {}

class Child extends Parent {}

const name = Object.getPrototypeOf(Child).name;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)